# Need help in getting out of infinite loop in a mips code

Tags: loops, mips, infinite

I was trying to code Floyd's triangle in MIPS and for some reason, I cannot seem to figure out the problem but since my QTspim is crashing while I am running the code therefore I am guessing it is stuck in an infinite loop. I need help in getting out of the infinte loop. This is the part of code with the loops and everything :

```
main:

li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt  #Enter number of rows
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $t1, $v0  #rows

li $t2 , 1 #i
li $t3, 1 #j
li $t4 , 1 #number 

loop1:
    beq $t2, $t1 , exit
    li $t3 , 1
    
loop2:
    beq $t3, $t2 , newline
    li $v0 , 1
    move $a0, $t4
    syscall
    addi $t4 , $t4 , 1 #number++
    j loop2

newline:
    li $v0 , 4
    la $a0 , nline
    syscall
    addi $t2 , $t2 , 1
    j loop1
```

Comment: The condition to get out of `loop2` compares `$t3` and `$t2` to get out of it, neither of which you update in the loop. So if it enters the loop it will never get out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are not incrementing the inner loop i.e. loop 2 anywhere and therefore its having issues and is getting stuck in an infinite loop. Apart from that it looks fine. Here is my code:
main:

```
      li $v0, 4
      la $a0, prompt             
      syscall

      li $v0, 5                  #read number from console
      syscall
      move $t1, $v0
```

li $t2 , -1 #i
li $t3, -1 #j
li $t4 , 1 #number

loop1:
beq $t2, $t1 , exit
li $t3 , -1

loop2:
beq $t3, $t2 , newline
li $v0 , 1
move $a0, $t4
syscall
addi $t4 , $t4 , 1 #number++
addi $t3 , $t3 , 1 #j++
j loop2

newline:
li $v0 , 4
la $a0 , nline
syscall
addi $t2 , $t2 , 1
j loop1

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is at loop2 where you are comparing two equal registers $t2 and $t3, and when this loop starts looping, it never stops. You need to change the values of these register in order to make your loop halt.